# Gulp watch imports

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to watch my @imported scss files, but for some reason it stopped working. Can't remember changing anything:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

//style paths
var sassFiles = 'assets/css/scss/styles.scss',
    cssDest = 'assets/css/';

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('watch',function() {
    gulp.watch(sassFiles,['styles']);
});
```

My styles.scss:

```
@import
"fonts.scss",
"basics.scss",
"home.scss";
```

Whenever I change something in home.scss, I want it to watch, but it only watches styles.scss. Makes sense to me, but it used to work it the beginning..

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb)

> gulp.watch(glob[, opts], tasks)
>
> A single glob or array of globs that indicate which **files to watch**
>   for changes.

You watch only that files which are in *sassFiles*. You can change this line in such way

```
var sassFiles = 'assets/css/scss/**.scss',
```

or

```
var sassFiles = ['assets/css/scss/styles.scss',
'assets/css/scss/fonts.scss','assets/css/scss/basics.scss',
'assets/css/scss/home.scss'],
```

And all scss-files in folder *assets/css/scss/* will be watched.

If you would like to watch files by dependencies (*@import*) it is better to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)